# in WSO2 publisher, I get error when I import wsdl with basic authentication. Is there any solution?

Tags: soap, wso2, wsdl, basic-authentication, wso2-api-manager

in WSO2 publisher, I get error when I import wsdl with basic authentication. Is there any solution?
wso2 wsdl validator cannot validate this wsdl file. but it is valid! I guess it has schema in its types that has basic authentication too.
Is there any way to import this .wsdl file and soap API to WSO2?
[I got error when adding wsdl file that have basic Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cl7a.png)

Comment: Are there any errors in the server logs? Also, if possible can you attach the wsdl file you are importing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the WSDL file is basic auth protected, API Publisher is not able to retrieve the WSDL file. You have following options.

1. Download the WSDL file and provide the file to the API publisher
2. Host the WSDL file in a public location(Github) and provide the URL to the API Publisher

As WSDL file is basic auth protected I recommend to go with option 1 as you only download the file to your local machine and you don't share the file with the others.

Comment: thank you very much. but again it can not be validated by wso2. I guess it needs schema for this wsdl. And schema is protected again! so I can not upload .wsdl file! Do you have any idea?

Comment: thank you. also I downloaded schema and validation was successful.